# RxScala subscribe with multi Observer just emit event to first one

Tags: scala, rx-java, observable, rx-scala

I attempt use multi `Observer` subscribe a `Observable` which `onNext` occurred within a loop.It seems not work for every Observer.

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

object SubscribeMultiEvent extends App{
  val obv = Observable.apply[String]{ s =>
    def printForever: Unit = {
      s.onNext("hi~")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      printForever
    }
    printForever
  }

  obv.subscribe(s => println(s"first observer - $s"))
  obv.subscribe(s => println(s"second observer - $s"))

  Thread.currentThread().join()
}
```

Response just for the first Observer

```
first observer - hi~
first observer - hi~
...
```

Why second one can't receive the subscribe? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your codes is your `Observable` is synchronous. It means the second `subscribe` won't run until the first `subscribe` finishes. And since your `Observable` is never completed, the second `subscribe` won't be able to run.

To fix this issue, you need to make your `Observable` asynchronous. You can use `subscribeOn` to run in another Thread. E.g.,

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable
import rx.lang.scala.schedulers.NewThreadScheduler

object SubscribeMultiEvent extends App{
  val obv = Observable.apply[String]{ s =>
    def printForever: Unit = {
      s.onNext("hi~")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      printForever
    }
    printForever
  }.subscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler())

  obv.subscribe(s => println(s"first observer - $s"))
  obv.subscribe(s => println(s"second observer - $s"))

  Thread.sleep(60000)
}
```

`Thread.sleep(60000)` at the end is important. RxJava's Threads are daemon by default, and if the main thread finishes, because there is no more non-daemon threads, JVM will exit. To prevent the main thread from stopping, you need to add something like `Thread.sleep(60000)`.

Comment: Thanks,that's great.Furthermore, can I construct a loop emit event just this way but it iterate body subscribe on all observer every times? I don't want use new thread for every subscribe yet.

Comment: Looks like you need `publish`. See this example: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/a385e1a474a05af5173d3a6c5f380b0f87b50dff/examples/src/test/scala/examples/RxScalaDemo.scala#L438